# What are some good data recovery programs to try on an SD card?

Tags: video, recovery, data-recovery, sd-card

My friend imported a bunch of videos from his GoPro into iPhoto and foolishly let iPhoto delete upon successful import. He claims that iPhoto then quit unexpectedly and all of the videos are gone.

My guess is the files are still in the library but not in the index. I will have a look later today when I go to help him out. However, in case the files are really gone I'll try to recover them from the SD card.

Any suggestions for doing that?

Comment: My guess was right, the videos were still in the library's masters folder but not showing up in the application itself.

Answer (score 6):

I successfully used [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Main_Page) to get photos back from an SD card.